# Array indexing in Numpy python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, numpy

How can I define `_SOME CODE_` in the next code fragment in order to get the results shown below?

```
vector = numpy.array([a,b,c,d])
for i in xrange(4):
    print vector[_SOME CODE_ using i]
```

It sould give me those results:

```
[a,b,c]
[a,c,d]
[a,b,d]
[b,c,d]
```

The order is not important.

Comment: What's the intended pattern?  Add 1 to some vector components?

Comment: vector doesn't contain 3, so you cannot get the desired results with indexing alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer for the edited question**:

```
>>> vector = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> for i in xrange(4):
...     print numpy.r_[vector[:i], vector[i+1:]]
... 
[1 2 3]
[0 2 3]
[0 1 3]
[0 1 2]
```

**Answer for the original question**: Here's some random code producing the desired output:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> vector = numpy.array([0,1,2])
>>> for i in xrange(4):
...     print vector + (vector >= i)
... 
[1 2 3]
[0 2 3]
[0 1 3]
[0 1 2]
```

I've got no idea if this is what you want -- the requirement specification left some room for interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to find all combinations of size 3 of the vector. You can do this with [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) like this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import itertools
>>> vector = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> list(itertools.combinations(vector, 3))
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```